# Taking input and splitting into tokens repeats

Tags: c, scanf

So I have a simple function that just takes in some input and prints hello every time the function is run.

```
void takeInput(void) {

    char *ptrFirst;
    char input[50];
    scanf("%s", input);
    ptrFirst = strtok(input, " ");

    printf("hello");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    while(true) {
        takeInput();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I put the input "1 2 3 4" the word "hello" will be printed four times. I assumed the function would print hello once, then accept more input. Why is this happening?

Comment: The program doesn't terminate. `takeInput` is called forever.

Comment: Because you didn't read the manual for `scanf`?

Comment: `while (true) {...}` Will never terminate unless you put a `break` or `return` somewhere.

Comment: I've made some edits to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I put the input "1 2 3 4" the word "hello" will be printed four times. I assumed the function would print hello once, then accept more input. Why is this happening?

The `scanf()` conversion specifier `%s` reads **a sequence of non-whitespace characters**.

So `takeInput()` is called, you enter `"1 2 3 4"`, the `scanf()` processes the `1`, and the function returns.

It then is called three more times, processing the `2`, `3`, and `4` still in the input buffer.

Then the function is called a fifth time, and is waiting for input.

At no point is input tokenized by `strtok()`, because `input` never contains any whitespace to begin with.

You were probably looking for [`fgets( input, 50, stdin )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a whole *line* of input. (Check for the presence of that `\n` at the end to make sure you actually captured the *whole* input.)

Comment: Corollary: *Always* read the *full* documentation for the functions you are using *at least twice*.

Comment: Perhaps suggest `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)` instead? As long as `input` is an array of chars, it eliminates one source of bugs -- the duplicated size in the array declaration and the `fgets()` call. Just my opinion, though.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Breaks catastrophically if `input` gets passed in as a parameter, or dynamically allocated... you're damned if you do, damned if you don't. I could also have showcased something like `#define MAX_INPUT 50` or somesuch. In the end, *personally* I would recommend using C++. ;-)

Comment: Agreed. I'd personally go with POSIX.1 [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or better yet, implement a pair of functions where one reads the next token from the stream (into a dynamically allocated/resized buffer), without consuming a newline, and the other skips the rest of the line and the following newline, using say `getc()`. This approach works well for e.g. parsing CSV files, and is simple to write, in [tag:C] *and* [tag:c++]. And, if the input is human text in varying languages, you can easily extend it to wide input, which is nice wrt. sorting et cetera.